# issue with setting up a reverse proxy to fetch content from another page without changing the URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

we have a wordpress site `https://a.dev.example.com.au/` where we have created a blank page with path: `https://a.dev.example.com/overall-assessment-new/` now developer has a requirement to get the content from another page i.e `https://360-home.dev.example.com.au/` but it should not change the URL.

I tried various things on the `.htaccess` latest was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.dev\.example\.com\.au$
RewriteRule ^overall-assessment-new/$ https://360-home.dev.example.com.au/ [P]
```

and also tried to add some trick with `httpd.conf` but got `Internal Server Error` after that:

```
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
ServerName 127.0.0.1
SetEnvIfNoCase X-FORWARDED-PROTO "^https$" HTTPS

# Adding for forced https redirection of the site
<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
    
#ProxyPass for /overall-assessment-new/
ProxyPass "/overall-assessment-new/" "https://360-home.dev.example.com.au/"

ProxyPassReverse "/overall-assessment-new/" "https://360-home.dev.example.com.au/"

    # Other configurations...

</VirtualHost>
```

Not sure what am I missing here. I hope you guys can point out to fix this thing.

Comment: _"still no luck"_ isn't much of an actual problem description. Are you getting errors? Have you tried to enable rewrite logging, and checked what is happening in detail?

Comment: _"and also tried to add some trick with httpd.conf"_ - within your vhost for port 80, which redirects to the HTTPS version, the rest likely won't do much any more. If anything, your vhost for port 443 should be attempting to handle this.

Comment: yes, actually forgot to add their, after making the change in httpd conf, I got internal server error. Updated the question part as well

Comment: Then go and check what the error log has to say about that!

Comment: proxy:warn] [pid 31148] [client 10.0.0.49:32206] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /overall-assessment-new/ (scheme 'https'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure theproxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Comment: this is the error, please suggest me what I need to add?

Comment: Sounds like you only got `mod_proxy` activated, but not the sub-module `mod_proxy_http` that would also be necessary for this. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension#apache-working-as-a-reverse-proxy-using-mod-_proxy

Comment: now after adding virtualhost for 443 as well, Internal server error is gone, but still not able to redirect the content I can see blank page only.

but while checking the error log I can see:

`PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/<folder-name>/functions.php on line 146, referer: https://a.dev.example.com.au/overall-assessment-new/`

Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: So `hle.dev.homeloanexperts.net.au` is your `a` domain from the initial example, where the WordPress runs? Not sure why the error gives that URL as the _referrer_, that doesn't seem to make much sense. What `functions.php on line 146` contains, would be interesting to know. But if you are getting an error from the WP side of things, that makes me suspect you are still looking at the WP page, and that the attempt to proxy this request to the `360-home` site was not successful to begin with ...?

Comment: yeah, I have requested to responsible person to check the error, but meanwhile can I request you to edit your comment to a domain please :)